# Bash Fastest Way to Rewrite Screen

Tags: command-line, bash, performance, speed

I am using bash on Mac OS X as well as Lubuntu. One of the annoying things about when I make console applications is that

```
clear
```

will add a whole (x-number) of lines to the console. And then I rewrite the screen, which is time consuming and inefficient.

Instead I am looking for a way to make my app not create extra lines and rewrite characters that are currently shown. (like the "top" command)

For example, my app needs to make a number in the upper left corner of the console go up as fast as possible.

Example #1: Using clear

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in `seq 1 1000000`
do
    echo $i
    clear
done
```

This would be great besides that it "flickers", hangs sometimes, wastes console space, and is generally ugly.

Example #2: Using backspace

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -e "\033[8;5;10;t"
clear
echo -e -n "0"

for i in `seq 1 1000000`
    do
    echo -e -n "\b\b\b\b\b\b\b$i"
done
```

This one runs like a charm, doesn't create extra lines, and is quick, but it can only be run in small windows.

Example #3: Using the sort of rewriting formula that "top" and "alsamixer" do.

How would I do this example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at [this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/spice-up-your-unix-linux-shell-scripts.html); in particular I'd recommend the `tput` example, since that permits more or less exactly what you have in mind, and is fairly lightweight in a shell script -- which echoing escape sequences directly is not. `tput` also respects termcap/terminfo, which will help to make your scripts more portable.

Comment: I concur. tput is the way to go. You can check an example of `tput` usage here: http://wondershell.blogspot.de/2013/01/cpu-usage-graph-in-console.html

Comment: @Aaron Miller Does tput work on all UNIX-like systems?

Comment: `tput` should work on anything that interprets ANSI escape sequences, which should cover just about all terminal emulators you'd find on a Unix/Linux/&c. system, and considerably more besides.

Comment: `tput` forks a process and is far slower than echoing escape sequences directly (something like 150x slower on my computer!)

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for [`\r`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return), the carriage return character. It causes new text to overwrite whatever is at the cursor's position:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in `seq 1 1000000`
    do
    echo -e -n "$i\r"
done
```